# 32 bit COM client talking to 64 bit COM server and the other way around

Tags: com

Folks, can 64 bit COM client talk to 32 bit COM server?   What about the other way around?  I believe the answer is "YES", but wanted to double check.   THank you

Answer (score 2):

As long as the server is out of process (an EXE and not a DLL), it is not a problem from 32 to 64 or from 64 to 32.

Comment: Well, we're not allowed to put up links... because links disappear. I can say for a fact that I have worked on a Windows application that is both an OLE server and container. OLE is COM plus a bunch of other stuff. We have embedded Word and Excel from 32 to 64 and 64 to 32. And also our docs have been embedded in Word and Excel 32 to 64 and 64 to 32.

Comment: I know it works well, the remark was not for me. You're perfectly allowed to give a link if you quote the important parts, for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/process-interoperability or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/interprocess-communication or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/32-bit-and-64-bit-interoperability